# JavaScript - Issues with Intervals on browsers tab switching

Tags: javascript, tabs, intervals, clearinterval

I've got a simple script that fades in and out some images. It works perfectly fine, before I switch to another tab and then switch back. After switching back seems that interval that runs animation doesn't get cleared and `animateFading` function keeps running.

Why is it happening, how does tab switching affects script? And how could I make it work properly? thx!

The real code:

```
var img0 = document.getElementById("image0");
var img1 = document.getElementById("image1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("image2");

var imgs = [img0,img1,img2];

var intervalFading;
var intervalAnimate;

var imgThis = 0;
var imgNext = 1;

var fadeIn = 0;
var fadeOut = 1;

var start;



function animateFading() {
    fadeIn+=0.1;
    fadeOut-=0.1;
    imgs[imgThis].style.opacity = fadeOut;
    imgs[imgNext].style.opacity = fadeIn;

    if (fadeIn >= 1) {
        clearInterval(intervalAnimate);

        if (imgNext < 2) {
            imgNext++;
        } else {
            imgNext = 0;
        }

        if (imgThis < 2) {
            imgThis++;
        } else {
            imgThis = 0;
        }

        fadeIn = 0;
        fadeOut = 1;
    }

}

function fading() {
    intervalAnimate = setInterval(animateFading,50);
}

function startFading() {
    start = setInterval(fading, 3000);
}

window.addEventListener('load', startFading);
```

**Solution:**

```
var startedFading = false;

function startFading() {
    if (!startedFading) {
        startedFading = true;
        startFading = setInterval(fading, 5000);
        }
}

function stopFading() {
    startedFading = false;
        clearInterval(startFading);
}


window.addEventListener('focus', startFading);      
window.addEventListener('blur', stopFading);
```

The boolean is for Chrome, as it fires twice

```
window.addEventListener('focus', startFading);
```

&

```
window.addEventListener('blur', stopFading);
```

Comment: using a recursive function that calls setTimeout vs using setInterval tends to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers have  a feature that redirects the memory usage capacity to the only active tab (currently being viewed). Thus, the `setInterval` and `setTimeout` timings are affected when you switch the current tab (if you're using Google Chrome, you can see the memory usage of each tab by pressing Shift+Esc. The current tab will use up to 25%, whereas the rest don't pass of the 5%)

Comment: @lolikroli See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome